# Why does using string is right while not using string is a problematic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this code to output 5% as a tax.

```
income = input('How much is your income?')

tax =  income / 20



print('The tax would be  ' + tax )
```

Why does it not work this way?

It gave me an error.

Comment: As for why it does not work that way, a string is not a number. What is the answer to `"Hello" / 20`?

Comment: Never say "it gave me an error" without adding that specific error. Python gives an extensive traceback; including it in your post helps us help you.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string by default. You need to manually cast it to an int or float like so:

```
income = float(input('How much is your income?'))
```